# Assigning one variable to another in Bash

Tags: linux, shell, variables

```
ip="192.168.1.1"

if [ -n "$(ip = 192.168.1.1)" ];
then
IPADDR=$(ip addr show |grep 'inet '|grep -v 127.0.0.1 |awk '{print $2}'| cut -d/ -f1)
else
"${ip}"="${IPADDR}"
fi
echo "${IPADDR}"
```

Im trying to assigning `ip="192.168.1.1"` to variable `IPADDR`

the error im geting atm is
Object "=" is unknown, try "ip help".
./test: line 7: 192.168.1.1=: command not found

Comment: You should try running your script through [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net), just make sure you add the initial shebang line so it knows which shell to test against.  One hint: I'm fairly certain that `if [ -n "$(ip = 192.168.1.1)" ];` wouldn't be doing what you think it does even if it were syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ...

> ```
> if [ -n "$(ip = 192.168.1.1)" ];
> ```

... you are executing the *command* `ip`, passing arguments `=` and `192.168.1.1`, and capturing its standard output.  These are not valid arguments for that command, so `ip` emits an error message to its standard error, but nothing to its standard output.

The test `[ -n "$(ip = 192.168.1.1)" ]` evaluates whether the captured output is non-empty, so this test fails, and consequently, the `else` block is executed.  Here ...

> ```
> "${ip}"="${IPADDR}"
> ```

... is not a variable assignment but rather a command, because the text to the left of the `=` is not (just) an identifier.  The `IPADDR` variable is unset or null, so that expands to `192.168.1.1=`.  The shell reports that there is no command of that name.

It's hard to be sure what you were really trying to accomplish, but going with the question title, if you want to assign a value to a variable then the syntax is

```
variable_name=value
```

The `variable_name` must be an identifier.  The `value` is subject to expansion and quote removal, but not word splitting, so either of these would work for what you appear to be trying to do

```
ip="${IPADDR}"
```

or

```
ip=${IPADDR}
```

.  With that said, the code does not make sense, because it does not assign a value to variable `IPADDR` before attempting that assignment.

Earlier, it is possible that you meant

```
if [ "$ip" != 192.168.1.1 ]
```

... which tests whether the value of variable `$ip`, considered as a string, is equal to the string `192.168.1.1`.  Even then, however, the code does not make sense overall.